# I want to call a Jar file in WebContent folder, but getting an error

Tags: eclipse, jsp, executable-jar

I want to call a Jar file which is in WebContent folder. I wrote the JSP as the below written, however getting an error.

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar / C:\Users\avik\workspace1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Praat\MyFile/simpleJarTester.jar");
```

What is the remedy?

Comment: What is the error you are getting, add in description.

Comment: is it a correct syntax to call jar? (filePath is the path variable)

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar" + filePath + "simpleJarTester.jar" + " " + "input" + filePath + " " + "out.text");

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to run `jar` file like this? It's always better to add a `jar` to **`WEB-INF/lib`** folder and call the functionality by method call.

**Your code have two issues:**

1. No need to add backslash as your string is already in double quotes
2. You have wrong slash after MyFile.

**Solution:** Try either

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar C:\Users\avik\workspace1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Praat\MyFile\simpleJarTester.jar");
```

Or

```
try {
      Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
      Process exec = runtime.exec(new String[]{"java", "-jar", "C:\Users\avik\workspace1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Praat\MyFile\simpleJarTester.jar"});
      int i = exec.waitFor();
      System.out.println(i);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```